# How to parse string that contains objects as a string to list of objects - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I had a list of objects and saved them as a String in shared preferences. Now I need to extract that saved string and convert it back to the list of objects. So how to convert this kind of string

```
[DataClass(label=testLabel, testData=someData), DataClass(label=testLabel, testData=someData)]
```

To `val result = listOf<DataClass>()`

So as result I will be able to get data from `dataclass.label` and `dataclass.testData`

Comment: This looks like the output of `toString()`, and there's no canned "from string" to reverse it. You could instead encode your list as JSON; there are many libraries that can handle converting to/from json text.

Comment: If you're going to be converting objects to Strings and back (a form of serialisation) then you should really be looking at a serialisation library - Kotlin has one: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html You *could* write some code to parse those strings you have, extract the data, and use it to create your objects to match that state - but that's extremely brittle

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with @BenP's and @cactustictacs
suggestions in the comments below your question.

```
val str = "[DataClass(label=testLabel, testData=someData), DataClass(label=testLabel, testData=someData)]"

data class DataClass(
  val label: String,
  val testData: String
)

val result = str
  .removeSurrounding("[DataClass(label=", ")]")
  .split(", testData=", "), DataClass(label=")
  .chunked(2)
  .map { DataClass(it[0], it[1]) }

result.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: this just handles this particular example. But how to handle it in general?

Comment: You adapt the code to reflect your data class.

Comment: could you explain what `removeSurrounding` and `split` do in your code?

Answer (score 0):

As all other comments and answer recommend you to use a `serialization` library instead of manually converting `string` to the `object`, because it would be more idiomatic, less error-prone, and easier to maintain.

You can use `Kotlin-Serialization` for this. To enable it, perform these three steps

Add `kotlin-serialization` plugin to `dependencies` of your project-level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    //..
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    //..
}
```

Apply plugin in your module-level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "kotlinx-serialization"
```

Add `Json` encoder dependency to module's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:2.0.1"
}
```

---

To `serialize` your `data class` annotate it with `@Serializable`

```
@Serializable
data class DataClass{
    val label: String,
    val testData: String
}
```

Now to convert list of `DataClass` to `String` just use `encodeToString` method of `Json` class.

```
val dataClassList = listOf(DataClass("dfd", "fdf"), DataClass("dfd", "fdf"), DataClass("dfd", "fdf"))
val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(dataClassList)
```

Save `jsonString` to `shared preferences`

To convert it back to the list of `DataClass` use `decodeFromString` of `Json` class.

```
val decodedDataClassList = Json.decodeFromString<List<DataClass>>(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Gson, instead of calling toString() as already mention, there's no fromString() method.

```
private fun DataClassToJson(data: Data): String {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    return gson.toJson(data)
}

// save the string to preferences and retrieve it

private fun jsonToDataClass(data: String): Data {
    val dataType = object : TypeToken<Data>() {}.type
    // convert string back to object
    return Gson().fromJson(data, dataType)
}
```

Comment: you will need to implement Gson library in build.gradle
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8"

Comment: is this implementation works with the list or just single object?

Comment: works with Any object, including list.  what gson does is create a string with json structure. {}